# C# Get Initials of DisplayName

Tags: c#, backend, dto

I'm trying to extract initials from a display name to be used to display their initials.
I'm finding it difficult because the string is one value containing one word or more. How can I achieve this?

Example:

'John Smith' => JS

'Smith, John' => SJ

'John' => J

'Smith' => S

```
public static SearchDto ToSearchDto(this PersonBasicDto person)
        {
            return new SearchDto
            {
                Id = new Guid(person.Id),
                Label = person.DisplayName,
                Initials = //TODO: GetInitials Code
            };
        }
```

I used the following solution: I created a helper method which allowed me to test for multiple cases.

```
public static string GetInitials(this string name)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            string[] nameSplit = name.Trim().Split(new string[] { ",", " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var initials = nameSplit[0].Substring(0, 1).ToUpper();

            if (nameSplit.Length > 1)
            {
                initials += nameSplit[nameSplit.Length - 1].Substring(0, 1).ToUpper();
            }

            return initials;
        }
```

Comment: Are you assuming that you always use the first letter after a space character?  Can you specify any (other) such assumptions?  (In the case of spaces, a typical pattern is "split, take first character of each element, join.")

Comment: Aside: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple and easy to understand code and handles names which contain first, middle and last name such as "John Smith William".

Test at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kmaXXE

```
 Console.WriteLine(GetInitials("John Smith"));  // JS
 Console.WriteLine(GetInitials("Smith, John")); // SJ
 Console.WriteLine(GetInitials("John"));        // J
 Console.WriteLine(GetInitials("Smith"));       // S

 Console.WriteLine(GetInitials("John Smith William"));   // JSW
 Console.WriteLine(GetInitials("John     H       Doe"));   // JHD


 static string GetInitials(string name)
    {                       
        // StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries excludes empty spaces returned by the Split method

        string[] nameSplit = name.Split(new string[] { "," , " "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    
        string initials = "";

        foreach (string item in nameSplit)
        {                
            initials += item.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper();
        }

        return initials;           
    }
```

Comment: test for: `"John       Smith            William"` ?

Comment: @Kiquenet, you get JSW. Are you getting a different result?

Comment: @Jamal ,  Never modify string inside of any loop. it will create a new string object on the memory heap instead of modifying an original string at the same memory address. The StringBuilder doesn't create a new object in the memory but dynamically expands memory to accommodate the modified string.                                               StringBuilder initials = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (string item in nameSplit)
            {
                initials.Append(item.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper());
            }

            return initials.ToString();

Answer (score 10):

Or just another variation as an *extension method*, with a small amount of sanity checking

**Given**

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
   public static string GetInitials(this string value)
      => string.Concat(value
         .Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
         .Where(x => x.Length >= 1 && char.IsLetter(x[0]))
         .Select(x => char.ToUpper(x[0])));
}
```

**Usage**

```
var list = new List<string>()
{
   "James blerg Smith",
   "Michael Smith",
   "Robert Smith 3rd",
   "Maria splutnic Garcia", 
   "David Smith", 
   "Maria Rodriguez",
   "Mary Smith", 
   "Maria Hernandez"
};

foreach (var name in list)
   Console.WriteLine(name.GetInitials());
```

**Output**

```
JBS
MS
RS
MSG
DS
MR
MS
MH
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xIuoCj)

Comment: benchmark about it ? [benchmarkdotnet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html)

Answer (score 3):

How about the following:

```
   void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetInitials("John Smith"));
    Console.WriteLine(GetInitials("Smith, John"));
    Console.WriteLine(GetInitials("John"));
    Console.WriteLine(GetInitials("Smith"));
}

private string GetInitials(string name)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    var splitted = name?.Split(' ');
    var initials = $"{splitted[0][0]}{(splitted.Length > 1 ? splitted[splitted.Length - 1][0] : (char?)null)}";
    return initials;
}
```

Output:

JS - SJ - J - S

Answer (score 0):

the code below is from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-find-initials-name/). what the code does is take the first letter of every word from the string and outputs it as capital letters.

```
   static void printInitials(String name) 
    { 
        if (name.Length == 0) 
            return; 
  
        // Since touuper() returns int, 
        // we do typecasting 
        Console.Write(Char.ToUpper(name[0])); 
  
        // Traverse rest of the string and  
        // print the characters after spaces. 
        for (int i = 1; i < name.Length - 1; i++) 
            if (name[i] == ' '&((i + 1)!=name.Length)) 
                Console.Write(" " + Char.ToUpper(name[i + 1])); 
    }
```